# Generating the distance of an intersection through a box from the camera in Unity C#

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl

So, I recently saw this fantastic video by Sebastian Lague about planetary generation-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lctXaT9pxA0&t=1100s
And I decided to replicate it, however, on a flat plane, not a sphere.In the video, (at timestamp linked) he uses some mathematical expression to  figure out the distance of the camera's vector through an arbitrary sphere, and uses this to shade the ocean. I can't figure out how to write a similar estimator for an arbitrary rectangular prism. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT- I have shifted to using surface shaders, but I can't figure out how to compensate for distance in depth-

````
Shader "Custom/SurfaceDepthShader"
{
    Properties {
        _ColorShallow ("Color Shallow", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _ColorDeep ("Color Deep", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5

        _fadeDepth("Base Alpha", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        
        _InvFade ("Soft Factor", Range(0.01,3.0)) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        LOD 200
       
        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard vertex:vert alpha:fade nolightmap
 
        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0
 
        sampler2D _MainTex;
 
        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float4 screenPos;
            float3 worldPos;
            float eyeDepth;
        };
 
        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _ColorShallow;
        fixed4 _ColorDeep;
 
        sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
        float4 _CameraDepthTexture_TexelSize;
       
        float _InvFade;
        float _fadeDepth;
 
        void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
            COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.eyeDepth);
        }
 
        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _ColorShallow;
            //
            //  smoothness come from slider variables
            
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
 
            float rawZ = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE_PROJ(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(IN.screenPos));
            float sceneZ = LinearEyeDepth(rawZ);
            float partZ = IN.eyeDepth;
            
            float dist = distance(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, IN.worldPos);

            
 
            float fade = 1.0;
            if ( rawZ > 0.0 ) // Make sure the depth texture exists
                fade = saturate(_InvFade * (sceneZ - partZ));
            
            
            
            o.Albedo = lerp(_ColorShallow, _ColorDeep, fade) * c;
            o.Alpha = c.a * fade * _fadeDepth;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```
````

Comment: It looks like you might have linked the wrong timestamp - can you confirm? [If you're just looking for a ray-box intersection, we have existing Q&A about that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=ray+box+intersection).

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, wrong timestamp- https://youtu.be/lctXaT9pxA0?t=944 This is sort of about cube ray intersection, but the samples I am seeing do not apply to a shader and also do not include a way to get distance travelled through the cube.

Comment: Hint 1: any math can be converted to shader math with a little elbow grease. Hint 2: the math for finding where you exit the cube is the same as the math for finding where you enter it. If you have trouble adapting an existing answer to your case, post your attempt and ask how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure I understand what you're asking, because it seems like you linked to the wrong timestamp in the video. It sounds like you're asking how to change the color based on distance from the camera. If so:

Unity has a [built-in shader variable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html) `_WorldSpaceCameraPos` which represents the world-space position of the camera.

You can track the world-space position of a pixel in a vertex/fragment shader like this:

```
struct appdata {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
};

struct v2f {
    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
    float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD0;
};

v2f vert (appdata v) {
    v2f result;
    result.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    //Calculate the world position of this pixel:
    result.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
    return o;
}
```

Then in your frag function you can check the distance and perform math based on that:

```
fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
    //calculate distance from camera to pixel
    float dist = distance(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, i.worldPos);
    
    //do some math using the distance to determine your final color.
    //this is a very simple example:
    float blue = (1000 - dist) / 1000; //black at 1000m, pure blue at 0m
    blue = clamp(blue, 0, 1);
    fixed4 color = fixed4(0, 0, blue, 1);
}
```

**Edit:** Okay, now having seen the correct section of the video, it seems like you're wondering how to shade the ocean based on the depth of the ocean. I don't think my above code is directly applicable.

I am a little confused about the approach he's using in the video. He says "this shader will be run for every pixel on the screen", which sounds like he's using a screen-space shader. I may be missing something, as I have not watched the entire video, but that does not seem like an optimal solution to me. If I understand correctly, he has to do a bunch of extra math to determine which pixels, out of all of the pixels on the screen, are actually part of the ocean, then shade them according to the depth buffer.

The way I would do this would be to use a material shader, not a screen-space shader. If you were making a spherical world like in the video, you would do this:

1. Add a sphere to the scene at the same position as the planet, and give it a radius that matches your desired ocean depth.
2. Author a material shader that determines color based on the depth buffer, similar to way he does in the video.
3. Create a material that uses the material shader from step 2, and assign it to the sphere you created in step 1. Now you have your ocean and don't need to perform screen-space calculations to determine which pixels onscreen should be considered "ocean" pixels.

If you're doing a flat world, just make the ocean a plane instead of a sphere, and position it to achieve your desired ocean depth.

Comment: I understandhow to do that, but of course, I don't want the entire screen. Sorry, this is the right timestamp- https://youtu.be/lctXaT9pxA0?t=944

Comment: It doesn't have to be the entire screen with Kevin's answer. You can use this shader on a cube mesh in your scene. You can even read the exit depth out of the depth buffer if you render an invisible copy of the box inside-out first.

Comment: @Spaceguy99 The shader I described would be a material shader, not a screen-space shader. It sounds like what he's doing in the video is creating a screen-space shader that makes everything a lot more complicated than it needs to be. I've updated my answer with some suggestions on how you might approach this.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks so much! I was able to write this- https://imgur.com/ukjZHna However, there IS one problem with it, one that is harder to express in an image- if you get close to the water, in the area where land and water meet, there is some weird dark shadows that don't show from a distance (and in fact, fade away in the screenshot as islands are farther from the camerea) https://imgur.com/a/A9QDk1I

Comment: @Kevin Second problem with this approach is that this is NOT the amonut of water that light passes through, but rather the depth of the camera FROM the water.  Therefore, the results are very different depending on the position of your camera.

Comment: @Spaceguy99 Can you add some screenshots to your question?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it can be seen here- First is taken up close, second farther away- notice the color of the water- https://imgur.com/gallery/88su8qX

Comment: @Spaceguy99 Thanks. I think you could solve this by scaling the depth effect based on the distance from the camera to the surface pixel (the value you get from `float dist = distance(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, i.worldPos);` in my answer)

Comment: @Kevin I tried scaling by subtracting the distance from the Linear Eye Depth, but that leads to all sorts of visual glithces and cool, but unwanted results. This is my code ( ignore the dist part)- https://imgur.com/a/3bJNtPy Any ideas as to how to integrate distance?

Comment: @Spaceguy99 You might want to divide rather than subtract. If you could post that code in your original question (there's an Edit button below the question) so I could play around with it, that would make things a lot easier than having to re-type the code from your screenshot.

Comment: @Kevin Dividing didn't seem to work- I included my code n the OG post now,

Comment: @Spaceguy99 Please add the entire shader, not just the `vert()` and `surf()` functions.

Comment: @Kevin Added that! Thanks for all the help.

Comment: When I use the shader code you posted exactly as is, the appearance does not vary with _distance_ from the camera. It varies depending on the _angle_ of the camera relative to the water, which is an inherent problem with anything that uses the depth texture. It's possible that the extra sphere math in the video was meant to counteract this problem. Unfortunately I think this is as much as I can offer. @DMGregory might be able to help.

Comment: @Spaceguy99 Based on skimming the video more, I think his water has the same side-effect: the appearance of the water varies with angle. It's just less obvious because his ocean is spherical instead of flat; see e.g. the camera movement around 18:01 https://youtu.be/lctXaT9pxA0?t=1082